# Negation if statement

Tags: logic

Let p be the statement: 
'If n is an odd number then 4n-1 is a prime'
Find the negation of p.

My answer would intuitively be 
'If n is an even number then 4n-1 is a prime'
but I have the doubt that a possible answer might be 
'If n is an odd number then 4n-1 is not a prime'.

I would appreciate it if anybody could help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want the converse or the negation?

Comment: Negation,the way the question in my textbook was phrased confused me

Comment: Have the posted solutions explained the negation to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for the negation in the title, but the converse in the body of the question, so it's not clear which you mean.  Here are the definitions of each:

For an implication $p \implies q$ (i.e., "If $p$, then $q$"), the **converse** is the implication $q \implies p$ (i.e., "If $q$, then $p$").

The **negation** is the "not" statement, and for an implication $p \implies q$, the negation is $p \land (\sim q)$, i.e., "$p$ and *not* $q$".

Can you figure out the answer now based on your original implication?

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I confused the negation with the converse. 
This leads to a second question. 
So, if I understood correctly, if I were asked for the negation of the statement 
'if n is an odd number then 4n-1 is a prime'

the answer would be 
if n is an odd number then 4n-1 is not a prime?

Thanks

Comment: @Eli No, you've made a very common but important mistake.  Remember the following sentence:  **The negation of an "if, then" statement is NOT an "if, then" statement.**  The negation of the statement "if $p$, then $q$" is the statement "$p$ and *not* $q$".  In symbol, we write $\sim(p \implies q)$ is $p \land (\sim q)$.  So the negation of the statement "if it rains today, then I am a monkey" is the statement "it rains today **and** I am not a monkey".  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you.
Does this mean the answer is 'n is an odd number and 4n-1 is not prime'?

Comment: @Eli That's right.  Good job! :)

Answer (score 1):

The converse of $p \to q$ is $q \to p$. In your case, $p$ is "$n$ is odd" and $q$ is "$4n-1$ is prime". So the converse is

"If $4n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is odd. "

By the way, the first statement is not true; neither is the second, as $n = 3/4$ shows.